# What is "\" in JSON?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, casting, json-deserialization

I am practicing JSON parsing and I encountered this kind of JSON

```
{
"data": {
  "Location": "[{\"id\":\"asdiqwe321\",\"name\":\"Manila\",\"lat\":25.42952,\"long\":-96.7960712,\"rating\":3,\"address\":\"Manila Ph\"},{\"place_id\":\"zzxdasdqwe1235as\",\"name\":\"Quezon City Ph.\",\"lat\":12.523562,\"long\":24.663415,\"rating\":1,\"address\":\"Quezon City Ph\"},{\"place_id\":\"rtiDFSDQ1321\",\"name\":\"Makati\",\"lat\":32.151236,\"long\":21.24124561,\"rating\":3.5,\"address\":\"Makati PH\"}]"
}
}
```

I have a model and want to cast it there:

```
export interface Location{    
 place_id: string,
 name: string,
 lat: number,
 long: number,
 rating: number,
 address: number
}
```

This is my first time to encountered this type of JSON. I hope someone will help me and understand what is it.

Comment: It is used to mask the " 's in the payload

Comment: It's escaping double quotes.

Comment: Wow That's new to me. I will take note of that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a JSON Object, that's a string. The `\` character is used to escape the double quote `"`, otherwise JavaScript would interpret the double quote as the end of the string and would throw a parsing error.

If you want to access the string as an object, you need to parse it using `JSON.parse`:

```js
const obj = {
"data": {
  "Location": "[{\"id\":\"asdiqwe321\",\"name\":\"Manila\",\"lat\":25.42952,\"long\":-96.7960712,\"rating\":3,\"address\":\"Manila Ph\"},{\"place_id\":\"zzxdasdqwe1235as\",\"name\":\"Quezon City Ph.\",\"lat\":12.523562,\"long\":24.663415,\"rating\":1,\"address\":\"Quezon City Ph\"},{\"place_id\":\"rtiDFSDQ1321\",\"name\":\"Makati\",\"lat\":32.151236,\"long\":21.24124561,\"rating\":3.5,\"address\":\"Makati PH\"}]"
}
};


const locationString = obj.data.Location;
const locationObject = JSON.parse(locationString);
console.log(locationObject[0].id);
```

If you don't parse it, instead, `obj.data.Location` is just a string:

```js
const obj = {
"data": {
  "Location": "[{\"id\":\"asdiqwe321\",\"name\":\"Manila\",\"lat\":25.42952,\"long\":-96.7960712,\"rating\":3,\"address\":\"Manila Ph\"},{\"place_id\":\"zzxdasdqwe1235as\",\"name\":\"Quezon City Ph.\",\"lat\":12.523562,\"long\":24.663415,\"rating\":1,\"address\":\"Quezon City Ph\"},{\"place_id\":\"rtiDFSDQ1321\",\"name\":\"Makati\",\"lat\":32.151236,\"long\":21.24124561,\"rating\":3.5,\"address\":\"Makati PH\"}]"
}
};


console.log(typeof obj.data.Location);
```

You usually need to stringify or parse objects for serializations purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It is Array of object of type Location in serialized form.

```
var response = {
  "data": {
    "Location": "[{\"id\":\"asdiqwe321\",\"name\":\"Manila\",\"lat\":25.42952,\"long\":-96.7960712,\"rating\":3,\"address\":\"Manila Ph\"},{\"place_id\":\"zzxdasdqwe1235as\",\"name\":\"Quezon City Ph.\",\"lat\":12.523562,\"long\":24.663415,\"rating\":1,\"address\":\"Quezon City Ph\"},{\"place_id\":\"rtiDFSDQ1321\",\"name\":\"Makati\",\"lat\":32.151236,\"long\":21.24124561,\"rating\":3.5,\"address\":\"Makati PH\"}]"
  }
}
```

You have to parse it.

```
var locationData : Array<Location> = JSON.Parse(response.data.Location);
```